# SQL Server Data Tools updates and TFS Build

Tags: tfsbuild, sql-server-data-tools

When I update SQL Server Data Tools on my development workstation, do I need to update it on my TFS Build machine as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended best practice is to keep the tools in the development environment and TFS build machine in sync. Otherwise it's possible for a build to fail on the build machine but succeed locally.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a link to MS documentation which says that, would you? (I'll still accept this answer either way, but I wanted to ask first.)

Comment: @DavidWilson, Steven is correct that "You must install Visual Studio and also any other software and components that are installed on your dev machines and that are required to build your app." See "Install Visual Studio and other software to enable compilation and other capabilities" part in this MSDN article:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399135.aspx#software

Answer (score 0):

You don't strictly have to and it will work but I would keep updating it on the server as they release new versions every 3 months with lots of fixes in.

What I do is not install it on the build servers but checkin to a test project the exe and dll's for sqlpackage and use that in my CI process so that I can update it whenever I like and also it is simple to deploy deployment contributors.

Ed